# My player still rotate even with constraints

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want my player not to rotate anymore after the game starts. I freeze rotation in the script and in the constraints too , but the player still rotates when it moves forward . What can I do ? ( I have a fps , and a character controller) . I also have a canvas with buttons to control left , right ? Should I put the rigibody or player script inside the Character object ( I made a player game object that contains the character and the camera)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float playerSpeed = 1500;
    public float directionalSpeed = 20;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR || UNITY_STANDALONE || UNITY_WEBPLAYER

        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(gameObject.transform.position, new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(gameObject.transform.position.x + moveHorizontal, -2.5f, 2.5f), gameObject.transform.position.y, gameObject.transform.position.z), directionalSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
#endif
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = Vector3.forward * playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.z / 3);
        //MOBILE CONTROLS
        Vector2 touch = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition + new Vector3(0, 0, 10f));
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(touch.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        }
    }
    public void MoveLeft()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(-playerSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
    }
    public void MoveRight ()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(playerSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
    }
    public void StopMoving()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(0f, rb.velocity.y);
    }
    void DetectInput()
    {
        float x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        if (x > 0 )
        {
            MoveRight();
        }
        else if ( x < 0)
        {
            MoveLeft();
        }
        else
        {
            StopMoving();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you freeze the rigidbody rotation it only freezes it in regards to physics interactions, using the transform.Rotate method will still rotate your object  regardless of your constraints.   `transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.z / 3);`

Comment: If you remove `Rotate` it will stop rotating

Comment: put `rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();` at the beginning of `Start()` and then never call `GetComponent<Rigidbody>` anymore. just use `rb`. Calling `GetComponent` a lot can slow things down.

Comment: if I want my character to automatically when move left to rotate the same time left  it can?

Comment: Can you rephrase that? I don't think I understand what you are asking.

Comment: Have you added a static (non-rotating) source to the RotationConstraint component?

Answer (score 0):

If you added a rigidbody you can freeze the position or rotation
(no matter if rigidbody is 2d or no)
[image]

For first you have to declare the rigidbody

```
rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
```

And then you can freeze your rotation RigidbodyConstraints (the selected label in the screenshot)

```
rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationX;
//freeze only one rotation

rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionX | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionZ | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionY;
//freeze all rotations
```

to uncheck just type

```
rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None;
```

If your game is 2d just add 2d to all Rigidbodies texts

Comment: if it still rotating try to remove the transform component and then adding it

Comment: OP is rotating the transform manually. Containing the RigidBody will not stop the rotation.

Answer (score -1):

### Rotate using [MoveRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html)

Using the `Rigidbody` component constraints will only constrain the game object through the physics engine. You are currently rotating the transform manually.

From documentation:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    Quaternion deltaRotation = Quaternion.Euler(m_EulerAngleVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
    m_Rigidbody.MoveRotation(m_Rigidbody.rotation * deltaRotation);
}
```